# Problem with DNS: getting my host's default page with an error message

Tags: domains, dns, cpanel, ip-address

I bought a new website, and the company gave me another free domain name, so when I asked for the second they created it and they told me to change the DNS to look like the first one.

It's been a week waiting for it to propagate, today when I type the url I got this error message :

> If you are the web site owner, it is possible you have reached this page because:
>
> - The IP address has changed.
> - There has been a server misconfiguration.
> - The site may have been moved to a different server.

If you are the owner of this website and were not expecting to see this page, please contact your hosting provider.

When I try to add the second domain to my cPanel (Addon domain) I get also another error:

> The addon domain “abcdef.com” has been created.
>
> An account with that login already exists.

I tried to flush the DNS with `ipconfig /flushdns`, but It's not changing anything.

Comment: SORRY!
If you are the owner of this website, please contact your hosting provider: webmaster@xxxxx.com

It is possible you have reached this page because:

Check whether you have uploaded the file on the correct location and remove the web cache in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First verify that the nameservers are right. Then in cPanel under Addon Domains make sure it's not in there, it is then delete it and re-add it. If you still get the error you need to contact your host. There is something mis-configured in your cPanel account that they can easily fix.

Answer (score 1):

In CPanel check under Domains -> Parked domains, it might set up in there.

Can you give us the domain name so we can run a whois to check the nameservers & possibly look at the zone records if their nameservers are set up to allow this.

Answer (score 0):

I got this message when I set the A record for the website to the wrong value. I mistakenly copied the IP address from the ftp A record for the domain, rather than using the IP address for the actual host server. I didn't realise they would be different.